# Send invoices from Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, custom

We have a lot of customers requesting custom orders from us that are not available on the website. Is there any solution that would allow me to send a custom invoice to somebody from our magento back end and then auto populate that into our sales queue when the customer purchased it?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you can create order from admin panel in magento for that you can follow this article they show step by step how to add order from admin panel

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/order-processing/order-create.html

Hope this will help you